# Compare 2 dates and output all past dates (powershell)

Tags: powershell, date, compare

I have a problem with my powershell script. I import a csv with different dates and compare them with today.

I dont know why but I get 3 dates from the csv that are in the future.

[image: CSV Content]

The script:

```
$InfoCSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Script\BDR\Info.csv" -Delimiter ";"
$Date = Get-Date
$today = (Get-Date -format dd.MM.yyyy)

foreach ($Item in $InfoCSV){
$BDate = $Item.BDate
$BDate = $BDate -replace "yyyy",$Date.Year
$parsedBDate = Get-Date $BDate -Format "dd.MM.yyyy"
if($parsedBDate -le $today){
$Name = $Item.Name
Write-Output "$BDate"}
}
```

Output:
10.01.2023
06.02.2023
03.04.2023
06.05.2023
09.05.2023
02.07.2023
03.07.2023
07.07.2023
09.07.2023
02.08.2023
06.08.2023
02.09.2023

Where do the last 3 dates come from?

I would appreciat any answer.
Furthermore I would be happy when anyone has a better Idea how to store the dates or improve my script in any other way.

Thanks
Luca

Comment: From the output it looks like it's treating your ddmmyy dates as US mmddyy. Note that while inputs includes dates with a day higher than 12, none of the outputs do, so you're missing 23.06 and 30.06 that should be there, and between 06.08 and 02.09 it isn't returning 19.08. Everything after 02.09 has a day number higher than 7, so that's why the latter ones in the sequence aren't returned.

Comment: You should compare the dates in their "*object format*" - not as strings!

Answer (score 1):

For *chronological* comparison, parse your date *strings* into `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instances, as [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) suggests:

```
# Get today's date as a [datetime] instance.
$today = (Get-Date).Date

# ...

# Parse the CSV column value into a [datetime] instance.
$parsedBDate =
  [datetime]::ParseExact($Item.BDate, 'dd.MM."yyyy"', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

# Now $parsedBDate -le $today works as intended.
```